# Split string on portion of matched regular expression (python)

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a string `'ad>ad>ad>>ad'` and I want to split on this on the `'>'` (not the `'>>'` chars). Just picked up regex and was wondering if there is a way (special character) to split on a specific part of the matched expression, rather than splitting on the whole matched expression, for example the regex could be:

`re.split('[^>]>[^>]', 'ad>ad>ad>>ad')`

Can you get it to split on the char in parenthesis `[^>](>)[^>]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use lookarounds:

```
re.split(r'(?<!>)>(?!>)', 'ad>ad>ad>>ad')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zI8zD0/1)

The `(?<!>)>(?!>)` pattern only matches a `>` that is not preceded with a `<` (due to the negative lookbehind `(?<!>)`) and that is not followed with a `<` (due to the negative lookahead `(?!>)`).

Since lookarounds do not consume the characters (unlike *negated (and positive) character classes, like `[^>]`*), we only match and split on a `<` symbol without "touching" the symbols around it.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `\b>\b`

This will check for single `>` surrounded by non-whitespace characters. As the string in the question is continuous stream of characters checking word boundary with `\b` is simplest method.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zC5eX8/1)**

Comment: What if a single `>` is enclosed with spaces, or there is just a space on the right or left? Then, it will not work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: That's not in OP's specification. If that is the case then OP should specify all such **cases**.

Comment: I marked the other as correct as it reflects the exact match I was after (but without consumption, which is new to me..)

Comment: @dpdenton: Whatever suits your case :-)