# How to prevent `re.sub` from `rstrip`ing?

Tags: python, regex

Say you have

```
>>> txt
' * a * ***b*** *c '
```

I want to replace all non-repeated occurrences of `'*'` by `'!'`. Thus, I thought

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('[^\*]\*[^\*]', '!', txt)             
'!a!***b***! '
```

would do the job. But where is my `'c'` ? I.e. how to keep it ?

Comment: Use lookarounds: `re.sub(r'(?<!\*)\*(?!\*)', '!', txt)`

Comment: @keepAlive you are removing the spaces too? this why He told you to use lookarounds

Comment: I already answered an identical question, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36339947/split-string-on-portion-of-matched-regular-expression-python/36339986#36339986)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookaround

```
(?<!\*)\*(?!\*)
```

- `(?<!\*)` - Match should not be preceded by `*`
- `\*` - Match `*`
- `(?!\*)` - Match should not be followed by `*`

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/fe4FXk/2/)

Comment: Down voter care to comment

Comment: It's not me but I think your answer is all ready in the comments?

Comment: @CharifDZ Yep I know. Actually I have removed a comment in which I was asking Wiktor to rewrite his comment as an answer.

Comment: @keepAlive you can change the replace value with whatever you want, you can play with the demo, by replacing with different value [`Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/fe4FXk/3/)

Comment: Yep sorry. At first I tried to also remove the `!`s within `(?<!\*)`, which has actually nothing to do with the replacement value.

Comment: @CharifDZ there's difference between a comment and answer, as far as i know it's not considered as a good practice to post answer as comment on SO, [`comment or answer what's etiquette`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17450), also there's very short time difference between the comment and answer, if the downvoter just thinks that is enough for downvote i am happy to have downvote

Comment: @CodeManiac I agree I hate when they do this too specially in regex tag